# Print msg to the console from GUI app - C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, console

Hi
I want to print some messages when I'm running C# GUI app on Visual Studio. It's like debugging. So I tried it, but not worked. console.writeline() didn't work or It may work, but I couldn't see the messages. Anyone knows about this? give me a solution if you know.
Thank you.

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx), which will print to Visual Studio's Output window.

Answer (score 6):

Console.WriteLine("Application Started!!");

that will also write into output window.

Comment: Does it work if you don't have a console? That's what OP is asking.

Comment: @theninjagreg: Ofcouse this will write in `Output Window`

Answer (score 1):

You can also run the app as a console app and then you'd have a console window as well as the form - simply change the setting in the Project Properties.

Comment: I'll see. But Output window can do it as well.

Comment: Yes it can. I find that having a console window is sometimes more convenient though.